DataGridView Binding does not refresh when updating list in bound object
I am building a wizard to review shop drawings before they get issued to the shop. I have created a custom class for this and each IssueItem has lists for found files, notes, and a bill of materials. I have implemented a binding source to the ProductionIssuer class which contains an ObservableCollection of IssueItems. I have 3 DataGridViews in my form showing the found files, notes and BOM. I have bound my data to these datagridviews as below

Data Bindings
filesDGV.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("DataSource", misBS, "FileInfos",true,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
notesDGV.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("DataSource", misBS, "Notes", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
bomDGV.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("DataSource", misBS, "BillOfMaterial", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));

These tables update just fine when I cycle through the binding source but when I try and update these lists the change is not reflected in the DataGridView. I can see that the DataSource is updated how ever the DataBindingComplete is never fired.
Below is my IssueItem Class I recently changed all my lists to ObservableCollections as well as implemented INotifyPropertyChanged
IssueItem Class
public class IssueItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Mark { get; set; }
    public List<IssueQuantityInfo> QuantityInfo { get; set; } = new List<IssueQuantityInfo>();
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }        
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Finish {  get; set; }
    public bool MainMember { get; set; }
    public IssueCategory Category { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<IssueFileInfo> FileInfos { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IssueFileInfo>();  
    public IssueItemOrderInfo OrderInfo { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<IssueNote> notes;
    public ObservableCollection<IssueNote> Notes 
    { 
        get 
        {
            if(notes == null) { notes = new ObservableCollection<IssueNote>(); }
            return notes;
        } 
        set { SetField(ref notes, value); }
    } 
    public DataTable BillOfMaterial { get; set; } = new DataTable();
    public bool Changed { get; set; }
    public bool OnHold { get; set; }
    public bool DetailingError { get; set; }
    
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public bool HasCAD { get; set; }
    public string Material
    {
        get { return Section + Size; }
    }
    public int TotalQuanity
    {
        get { return QuantityInfo.Sum(x => x.Quantity); }
    }
    public bool DrawingFound
    {
        get { return FileInfos.Count() > 0; }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
 => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    public IssueItem() { Initialize(); }
    public IssueItem(int id, string mark, List<IssueQuantityInfo> quantityInfo, string section, string size, string grade, int length, string finish, bool mainMember, IssueCategory category, ObservableCollection<IssueFileInfo> fileInfos, IssueItemOrderInfo orderInfo, bool onHold, bool detailingError, ObservableCollection<IssueNote> notes, bool deleted, bool hasCAD)
    {
        Initialize();
        Id = id;
        Mark = mark;
        QuantityInfo = quantityInfo;
        Section = section;
        Size = size;
        Grade = grade;
        Length = length;
        Finish = finish;
        MainMember = mainMember;
        Category = category;
        FileInfos = fileInfos;
        OrderInfo = orderInfo;
        OnHold = onHold;
        DetailingError = detailingError;
        Notes = notes;
        Deleted = deleted;
        HasCAD = hasCAD;
    }
    internal void Initialize()
    {
        Notes.CollectionChanged += Notes_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Notes_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("Notes"); 
    }        
    
    public string GetPaperSizes()
    {
        return string.Join("; ",FileInfos.Select(f => f.PaperSize).ToArray());   
    }
    public string GetPrinterPaperSizes()
    {
        return string.Join("; ", FileInfos.Select(f => f.PrinterPaperSize).ToArray());
    }
    
}

And here is the code that I am updating the notes (I am trying everything to get this table to refresh)
Error Note Adding
 private void errorCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
IssueItem issueItem = ((IssueItem)misBS.Current);
if (errorCheckBox.Checked)
{
    issueItem.Notes.Add(new IssueNote(_productionIssuer.GetIssueNoteTypes.GetIssueNoteType("Error Note"),"Detailing Error"));
}
else
{
    ObservableCollection< IssueNote> notes = issueItem.Notes.FindAll(x => x.NoteType == _productionIssuer.GetIssueNoteTypes.GetIssueNoteType("Error Note"));
    if (notes != null)
    {
        if(MessageBox.Show("Would you like to delete all " + notes.Count + " Error Notes Found for " + issueItem.Mark + "?", "Notes not removed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            issueItem.Notes.RemoveAll(x => notes.Contains(x));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please review the notes section and remove any applicable notes.", "Notes not removed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
}
misBS.ResetBindings(true);
notesDGV.Refresh();
notesDGV.Invalidate();
notesDGV.InvalidateRow(0);
notesDGV.InvalidateColumn(0);
notesDGV.InvalidateCell(0, 0);
}

If I switch to the next item and go back the DataGridView updates with the new information
I will also include my ObservableCollection Extension class for anyone want to quickly use this code.
ObservableCollectionExtensions
 public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
public static int FindIndex<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, Predicate<T> match)
{
    return ts.FindIndex(0, ts.Count, match);
}

public static int FindIndex<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, int startIndex, Predicate<T> match)
{
    return ts.FindIndex(startIndex, ts.Count, match);
}

public static int FindIndex<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, int startIndex, int count, Predicate<T> match)
{
    if (startIndex < 0) startIndex = 0;
    if (count > ts.Count) count = ts.Count;

    for (int i = startIndex; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (match(ts[i])) return i;
    }

   

    return -1;
}
public static int RemoveAll<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, Predicate<T> match)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = ts.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (match(ts[i]))
        {
            result++;
            ts.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
public static ObservableCollection<T> FindAll<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, Predicate<T> match)
{
    ObservableCollection<T> found = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    for (int i = ts.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (match(ts[i]))
        {
            found.Add(ts[i]);
        }
    }
    return found;
}

public static ObservableCollection<TSource> ToObservableCollection<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }

    return new ObservableCollection<TSource>(source);
}
}

Both the File Locations grid and the notes grid are set to allow user to add rows but once bound I am not able to do that which is maybe related to this problem.
